# How to get the activepageindex

Tags: delphi

How can I programmatically get the activepageindex from a dynamically created tabsheet on a page control.

I have searched on the net for a while without any luck.

I apologize in advance if the answer is way to obvious.

Comment: The `ActivePageIndex` property remains unchanged when you dynamically create a tab sheet. I think you wanted to ask for tab index of the just created tab sheet. If that is so, read the [`TabIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTabSheet.TabIndex) property value of your just created tab sheet (you can do it right after you assign `PageControl` *parent* to it).

Comment: Yup, I was looking at it wrong. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var
  NewTabSheet: TTabSheet;
begin
  NewTabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
  NewTabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;
  PageControl1.ActivePageIndex := PageControl1.PageCount-1;
```